# How to assign array to iterator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

I have function sendData which is call by onClick() after click button.
Some properties are send to java class by ajax and I receive "jsonResponse.properties" object.

How can I "refresh" my list "properties". I want to assign response by ajax "jsonResponse.properties" to "properties" (refresh my iterator without refreshing all page)

I try:  `$("#prop").val=jsonResponse.properties;` but it doesn't working. (jsonResponse.properties return correct array)

**JAVA:**

```
private List<PropertyValuesData> properties;
public List<PropertyValuesData> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }
    public void setProperties(List<PropertyValuesData> properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

public String addProperty() {
    //refreshing properties 
}
```

**JSP:**

```
 function sendData(){
      $.getJSON('resourceaddProperty', {
                        "prop" : propertyName
                    }, function(jsonResponse) {
                       $("#prop").val=jsonResponse.properties;
                    });
    }
<table>
   <tr>
         <s:iterator id="prop" value="properties" >
             <td><s:property value="name"/></td>
             <td><s:property value="desc"/></td>
         </s:iterator>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am not sure if problem is this ascription or that table is not refresh.

What I want to do:

I have table generated by iterator ( as you can see above). After click add record I want to refresh table  by adding new record without refreshing all page. I think that this is just problem. How can I refresh ONLY table ?

Comment: Can you please show the generated page that the browser sees (from View/Source), not the JSP.  Then, we can see what the actual HTML and actual Javascript looks like.  In addition, we need to know what `jsonResponse.properties` is and what you're trying to do with it.  If it's an array, what are you trying to do with the array?

Comment: FYI, `$("#prop").val=jsonResponse.properties;` is not meaningful jQuery.  We need to know what you're actually trying to accomplish in order to know what to suggest as the correct jQuery.